# Using SeriLog through a wrapper class

Tags: c#, logging, static, serilog

I have a solution with multiple .EXEs, WCF services, Windows Services, etc... I want to use SeriLog for logging in all of these but I don't want these projects to add SeriLog directly. I want them to depend upon a Frameword dll that has various things like email, configuration, etc... To that end I want to create a wrapper class in this Framework dll. All my projects can then just refer to this wrapper class (part of a dll they are already referring to). So, I want something like:

```
public class TheLogger : Serilog.ILogger
{
    private static readonly TheLogger instance = new TheLogger();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the singleton instance of TheLogger class.
    /// </summary>
    static TheLogger()
    {
        // Configure SeriLog
        var log = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
        Log.logger = log;

        // Need to point the instance to SeriLog's implementation ????
        instance = (TheLogger)log;

    }

    private TheLogger()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the singleton instance of TheLogger class.
    /// </summary>
    public static TheLogger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I would want the other projects to use syntax like

```
TheLogger.Instance.Information("I am here");
```

But obviously, TheLogger doesn't have the implementation provided by the SeriLog's Log.logger static logger. And without the reference to SeriLog I can't refer to Log.logger. To summarize, the question is how do I leverage SeriLog's Log.logger but wrap it in my own class?

Comment: I normally avoid that kind of wrapper class. It's more code for you to maintain for no extra benefit. Putting it in a Framework dll makes it even worse because every project that wants logging will have a dependency on other things like email configuration whether it needs it or not. It's tempting to create these "helper" projects but they are usually not worth it in the end.

Comment: @acfrancis This is an existing codebase and all my projects already have a dependency on the Framework dll. Besides, we have written some code to automatically provide sensible defaults for other configurable things. So that also isn't much of a concern.

Comment: OK, fine then. I'm not familiar with Serilog but if it's like log4net, I would make my wrapper class have a private instance variable of a concrete logger and a method `Information ` with a similar signature to the one from Serilog. Then your other projects would call `TheLogger.Information(...)` and not need to know what class `TheLogger` is wrapping.

Comment: did you tried without wrapper ? and another wrapper ?